# Generator function that yields alternating values of two lists

Tags: python, generator

The question seems very basic and easy at first glance, but I still had some trouble writing an efficient solution. The idea is to write a function, which takes two generators as an input and yields one item of each list. If either list is empty, it yields each item of the remaining list. Example:

```
 list(alternate("abcdefg", [1, 2, 3, 4])) == ["a", 1, "b",2, "c", 3, "d", 4, "e", "f", "g"]
```

what kind of worked, but looks very ugly:

```
def alternate(xs1, xs2):
    xs1 = iter(xs1)
    xs2 = iter(xs2)
    while xs1 and xs2:
        try:
            yield next(xs1), next(xs2)
        except StopIteration:
                for x1 in xs1:
                    yield x1
                for x2 in xs2:
                    yield x2
```

Especially I want to avoid transforming the inputs to an iterator in the beginning.
I tried using 2 simple for loops, but this obviously returned only the last value of each list, because one for loops finishes before the other starts. This is not a solve my problem question, I am rather looking for some code to improve writing code skills!

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip_longest` and `chain.from_iterable` together:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, zip_longest
>>> [ x for x in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest("abcdefg", [1,2,3,4])) if x is not None]
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

For something more explicit and similar to what you already have, handle each call to `next` separately, and break out of the loop immediately to iterate over the remainder of each iterator. Use `itertools.cycle` to alternate between the two iterators until one is exhausted.

```
from itertools import cycle

def alternate(xs1, xs2):
    xs1 = iter(xs1)
    xs2 = iter(xs2)
    for itr in cycle([xs1, xs2]):
        try:
            yield next(itr)
        except StopIteration:
            break

    yield from xs1
    yield from xs2
```

Comment: Could something similar to my solution (using only basic functionalities) be achieved without using `iter(xs)`?

Comment: Not unless you want to force the caller to pass iterators. `next` only works on iterators, and lists and strings are *iterable*, but not iterators.

Comment: See the `roundrobin` function in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for a more robust version that can handle more than 2 iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the above answer but here's a version that doesn't use any imports:

```
def alternate(xs1, xs2):
    xs1, xs2 = iter(xs1), iter(xs2)
    for e1, e2 in zip(xs1, xs2): # either xs1, xs2 exhausted by the end of this loop
        yield e1
        yield e2
    
    # pull remaining from the non-exhausted generator (if any)
    yield from xs1
    yield from xs2
```

If you want a version that doesn't transform the inputs into iterators and avoids using other libraries, the below would work, assuming both sequences are indexable.

```
def alternate2(xs1, xs2):
    n = min(len(xs1), len(xs2))
    for i in range(n):
        yield xs1[i]
        yield xs2[i]
    
    yield from xs1[n:]
    yield from xs2[n:]
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s going to be challenging to do away with `iter()`, as that’s kind of what it’s made for. If you can put up with that, this can be straightforward:

```
def alternate(a, b):
    ia = iter(a)
    ib = iter(b)
    
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(ia)
            yield next(ib)
        except StopIteration:
            break
            
    yield from ia
    yield from ib
```

1. Just try to yield the next item from each of the items in turn.
2. Once one of them is empty, yield the rest.

Answer (score 1):

(This is basically @chepner's answer from the comments, but I believe this is the right answer which deserves to appear here...)

You can use the `roundrobin` function from the [more-itertools project](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) (referenced from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)).

I include it here for convenience:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly simpler than @wLui's:

```
def alternate(xs1, xs2):
     xs1 = iter(xs1)
     xs2 = iter(xs2)
     for pair in zip(xs1, xs2):
         yield from pair
     yield from xs1
     yield from xs2
```